# System.out, System.err : often temporary debugging statements warning

Tags: java, netbeans, console-application

While writing a very simple multi-platform console application in Netbeans, I have noticed a consistent warning at the statements System.out.println() and System.err.println(), which states these are often temporary debugging statements.

And in details on Netbeans wiki [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_Hints), it states

> These are often temporary debugging statements, and should probably be
>   either removed from production code, or replaced by a more robust
>   logging facility.

Why is it like this and what should I be using then to print out messages to the user strictly in console application viewpoint.

I am using several of these statements to inform user like, the argument is not valid, or some access denied exception occurred, etc.

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: well it is just a warning, a general suggestion.  If it suits your purpose, then do not fret.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Yes indeed but then I wanted to know. If this should be removed from production code, then what are you actually supposed to use to print out messages? Of course, I am not writing something high end tool to distribute in public but still.

Comment: If you were just writing debug messages then it would be better to use something like java.util.logging or log4j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application will be updated and/or will become a part of another more complex system, these `System.out` and `System.err` calls will become less convenient than a properly implemented logging subsystem in your application.

And it will be necessary to rewrite these parts of code to provide the more consistent logging picture for an administrator/end-user.